# Ripping MP3s in Rhythmbox Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit)?

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, cd-ripping

I installed a couple of days ago Ubuntu 12.10 (64 bit).

I today tried ripping a CD in the MP3 format.

However, whenever I try to rip, it says it is missing an extra multimedia plugin "Gstreamer extra plug-ins (i386)".

I then try to install the :i386 version of the gstreamer-ugly plugins, but then I get the same problem but with the id3-demuxer (or something similar)

The Terminal output I get from both problems (but replace the "MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) encoder" with the "ID3-demuxer" name) is:

```bsh
james@clefairy:~$ rhythmbox

(rhythmbox:24122): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Rhythmbox-Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|0.10|rhythmbox|MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) encoder|encoder-audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, layer=(int)3
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed import gobject._gobject
```

It doesn't help that each time I have to install/remove the entire Gstreamer-ugly collection each time - I can't find that specific file.

The CD **plays** fine, it's the **ripping plugin** that doesn't seem to work.

I didn't have this problem previously on 12.04 (64 bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at mc4man's post at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2080739. Looks like we need to use a custom setting. Worked for me.

Comment: The solution is:
Go to Edit > Preferences > Music
Change 'Format settings' to 'Custom Settings'.

I kept Quality on 4 and sounded fine.

Comment: @PaulB Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Synaptic and then install `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse`
If it still doesnt work i would recommend installing LAME (mp3 encoding front-end)

I suggest using Synaptic, simply because it tends to do better at installing technical items

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Strangely enough, I can't find that package under the Multiverse

The closest I can get to is  'gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly'??

I've installed LAME and I'll try reinstalling the package above.

Comment: Still no luck... any other ideas?

Comment: check to make sure Sound Juicer is installed (a front end for cd ripping). I think Rhythmbox uses it.
Getting tired of all these front-end dependencies? (:
I don't know what else may be the issue..after googling it there doesn't seem to be much documentation on it eh?

Comment: I installed Sound Juicer separately and that worked fine. Rhythmbox is just broken for some reason. Strange.

But yes, very little documentation. I did find a couple of bug reports on Launchpad with the same problem, wasn't solved though.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst0.10-python/+bug/1070517

Comment: Sorry! I hope they get fixed soon!

Answer (score 0):

Open synaptic, install libmp3lame0 then reboot. You should now be able to rip to mp3 after starting Rhythmbox

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I already had it installed albeit 'manually'. I removed it, installed it again and rebooted.

This time when Rhythmbox said there was a plug-on missing, it did start to install it. However it disappeared before it had finished (seemingly).

I now get this terminal output (see next comment):

Comment: (rhythmbox:2973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Rhythmbox-Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|0.10|rhythmbox|MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) encoder|encoder-audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, layer=(int)3
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
Rhythmbox-Message: Missing plugins installed. Updating plugin registry ...

Comment: (rhythmbox:2973): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Rhythmbox-Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|0.10|rhythmbox|MPEG-1 Layer 3 (MP3) encoder|encoder-audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, layer=(int)3 (ignoring)
Rhythmbox-Message: All missing plugins are blacklisted, doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you're still having this issue but I've used dagrab for grabbing tracks and lame for mp3 encoding. I made a rip-script years ago that I recently re-wrote as I suddenly needed to rip *loads* of CDs.. It runs fine on my ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I've not added any uninstall menu-option yet and the PROXY settings don't work with the cddget (perl) I use nowadays BUT otherwise.. it seems to work fine https://github.com/OlaAronsson/nenRip

Answer (score 0):

After getting the missing extra multimedia plugin "Gstreamer extra plug-ins (i386)" pop-up and a dependency error after accepting recommended install of gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly (i386) the problem went away once I cleared the user configs by removing files under ~/.local/share/gstreamer-1.0/presets

ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233131